# Firebase freezes UI even when using DispatchQueue

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, grand-central-dispatch, freeze

From my understanding, Firebase performs operations off the main thread and shouldn't pause the UI while doing so.

The code below is a simplified example, but everywhere in my code, where I have a Firebase observer with code that updates the UI, the UI freezes while Firebase downloads data.

I've tried writing the same code in a new, clean project, and then the problem no longer exist. Could the problem be the installation of Firebase through pods? I'm also using GeoFire, could that affect in any way?

I have also tried to put the observer inside of a DispatchQueue.global().async block. I've tried removing any DispatchQueue code completely, but it is all the same.

```
func observe() {
  firebaseReference.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
      }
  })
}
```

Comment: You code looks solid, as far as I can tell. Looks like your *bug* is somewhere else...

Comment: There is no need to use GCD for updating the UI. Firebase already ensures that the callback gets invoked on the main UI thread.

Comment: I have tried without GCD and the problem still remains. I have just created a whole new project, and copied the code: same problem. It feels like that Firebase will not run in the background anywhere in my code.